# ParseDB JS SDK - query.find(...) returning only parts of object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, typescript

I'm currently working with the parse.com DB JavaScript SDK (v1.9.2) and doing a query as shown below. The problem with that is, that I get an object from my database that has fields that are undefined although the values are shown in the dashboard. I'm really confused.

```
class Test extends Parse.Object
{
     //Here are some private variables...
     private _name: string; 

     constructor(name: string)
     {
          super("Test");

         this._name = name;
         this.set("Name", name);  //If a new Test object is created, store it in the db when testObject.save() is called 

     }


     public get Name(): string
     {
          return this._name;
     }

     public set Name(name: string)
     {
          this._name = name;
          this.set("Name", name);  
     }
}
Parse.Object.registerSubclass("Test", Test); //As required by the SDK see link below
```

When I do a  query for a set of test objects like following:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Test);
query.equalTo("user", user);
query.find({
        success: (usersTestObjects: Array<Test>) =>
        {                
            usersTestObjects.forEach((item) =>
            {
                  alert("Hello: " + item.Name); // **
            });                
        }
    });
```

**: Here, item.Name is undefined although other values such as objectId, createdAt,..are available, but my private member variables as Name and others are not available, why? However, if I do item.get("Name") it suddenly appears.

Other information: Using ECMA Script 6 and parse sdk v.1.9.2 as required by the development guide at: [Parse JS Guide](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/js/guide/#getting-started)

Comment: Hi, can you please also paste your setters and getters ? it's enough to past only the setter and getter of Name

Comment: Have done it, thanks :)

Comment: it seems that the function .find() can work only with ParseObject, so eventhough you are saying you are downloading Test it will be downloaded as Parse Object... I am just wondering, why do you have problem using `item.get("Name")`  :-)... could you also share the whole code query of how you initialize it?

Comment: are you using typescript in your project?

Comment: Yes, I am using typescript. Sorry, forgot to mention.

@MazelTov It does not seem very intuitive to get only a ParseObject. The problem is that I believe that doing it always in the "item.get(..)" way leads to code that allows for more errors since once you forget to put the "item.get(...)" you will have an undefined value. I will edit the code with the whole query.